# Is there a way to create backup of entire SQL Server not just a single database?

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have a SQL Server that has many jobs in SQL Agent, Replication configuration and of course databases. At this moment we don't have any plan to take backup of entire server. I know how to take backup of a database and make scripts of SQL Agents. But is there a way to take backup of entire SQL Server and all it's configuration, setup and contents?

Comment: Ola's scripts https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html have an option to backup all user & system databases, this article has details of backing up server config https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/john_daskalakis/2014/10/27/script-to-export-the-configuration-of-sql-server/ and this on users and logins http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40844/after-moving-database-backup-restore-i-have-to-re-add-user. Otherwise I guess you're talking about OS level backups.

Comment: @marc_s, the SQL Server system database backups (master, tempdb) will cover logins, jobs, etc.  The setup options (e.g. authentication mode) are stored in the registry and handed by OS backups.